# find Ip Address of Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, networking, ip, azure-databricks, acl

I'm integrating a data source that uses an API with Azure Databricks.
Code goes in **timed out** due to firewall restrictions, we would like to open up the firewall in order to allow our code in Databricks Notebook to reach the API.

I'm using Databricks through **Azure Portal** deployed in West Europe region.
Network team asked for the correct range(subnet) to open the ACL in order for Databricks to comunicate with the API.
Note that I don't have to restrict people from Using Databricks, I've to find the correct ip range in
order to create Access Control list (ACL) rule

```
     Source(?) - destination(API endpoint) - port(known) - protocol(known)
```

**How do I determine Databricks external public IP Range to determine the right ACL ?**

I tried to run some code to find the ip of cluster but these ip are internal and not external ip.
Looked into Official Documentation in order to find some information, but they're only suggesting how to add ip's to use/not use Databricks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject

Comment: I found the reason why the ip address were different for databricks from Databricks Official documentation.
In the end, I found that ex colleague implemented a Network Security Group which has different ip.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the question for whom it may find suitable.

The scenario is this :
You've a databricks cluster with some notebooks that you're creating in order to integrate new data sources.
In every company there is a network team which is responsable of applying rules to firewall (as known as ACL).
Network team ask you what kind of rule you must open in the form of

```
Source IP - Destination IP - Port - Protocol
```

In most of case, Azure Databricks does not have an IP or a connection that you can log into the machine in which Azure databricks is Deployed, since it would defy all definition of Cloud services.
However,You can find the range of IP regions from [Databricks IP Regions List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/resources/supported-regions#ip-domain-azure)
and that would be the right IP's range to comunicate.

Meanwhile, it would be ok to use Public IP from Databricks Page but not the best practice, so, due to security reasons, you should implement a network security group.